# Solve a redundant system of linear equations in R

Tags: r, matrix, linear-algebra

I have a noninvertible matrix `A` and a vector `b` for which I believe there is a solution `x` to `Ax = b`. I would like to find an example of such `x`. When I try `solve(A,b)` in R it produces an error because `A` is singular. Is there any way to make R give me a random solution?

Comment: You should give an example of A and b for people to work with.  But without seeing that, how about `qr.solve(A, b)`?  Another possibility would be based on `lsfit(A, b)`.

Comment: @user2554330 Good point. I included an example in the answer I posted. I ended up trying `lm(b ~ A)` which gives an example solution.

Answer (score 0):

I eventually tried `lm(b ~ 0 + A)` which works. It will leave estimates for some columns as NA, which you can substitute for 0 to get an example solution. For example

`A = matrix(c(1,1,0,0),nr=2,byrow=F)`

`b = c(2,2)`

`lm(b ~ A)`

will produce coefficients 2 and NA for the two columns of `A`. `solve(A,b)`, `lsfit(A,b)`, and `qr.solve(A,b)` do not work.

Edit: `MASS::ginv(A) %*% b` works too.

Comment: You could also try `MASS::ginv(A) %*% b`.